# Can a GeoJSON GeometryCollection contain another Collection?

Tags: geojson

From a reading of the [spec](http://www.geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) it seems that a [GeometryCollection](http://www.geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#geometry-collection) is a Geometry and can contain geometry objects? But I want to be sure that this is really allowed before I file a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should be allowed. And I have tested it on OpenLayers at least, you can create a feature whose geometry is a GeometryCollection which contains another GeometryCollection by reading a geojson string (using OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON object).

Answer (score 5):

Update: nested collections are specifically NOT RECOMMENDED in the latest GeoJSON specification.

> To maximize interoperability implementations SHOULD avoid nested geometry collections. Furthermore, geometry collections composed of a single part or a number of parts of a single type SHOULD be avoided when that single part or a single object of multi-part type (MultiPoint, MultiLineString, or MultiPolygon) could be used instead.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-geojson-03#section-3.1.8