# Is a multiply nested GeoJSON still valid GeoJSON and can it be displayed by LeafLet.js?

Tags: shapefile, leaflet, geojson, elasticsearch

- Is this a valid GeoJSON?
- Can it be displayed using [LeafLet GeoJSON Layer](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson)?

```
"geometry": {
    "coordinates": [{
        "coordinates": [{
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [{
                "x": 63.176,
                "y": 34.354
            },
            ...
            {
                "x": 63.176,
                "y": 34.354
            }]
        }],
        "type": "Polygon"
    }, {
        "coordinates": [{
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [{
                "x": 69.169,
                "y": 32.875
            },
            ...
            {
                "x": 69.169,
                "y": 32.875
            }]
        }],
        "type": "Polygon"
    }],
    "type": "MultiPolygon"
}}
```

**Background:**

With the goal of displaying GeoJSONs(indexed in Elasticsearch as *geo_shape*) in a **LeafLet-based map** in my frontend.

- I retrieve them from a REST API featuring **SpringData**.
- The repository maps Elasticsearch-data to a generic [`org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoJson`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.0-M5/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/geo/GeoJson.html) interface, as my indexed data can contain *Polygons* or *Multipolygons*.
- Original shapes are indexed from a .shp file using **ogr2ogr**.

Comment: You can display any valid GeoJSON with Leaflet. To check if GeoJSON is valid, you can use any of validating sites, for example https://geojsonlint.com/

Comment: Yeah but, why do I have x, y coordinates in my objects? LeafLet cannot really work with this as far as I know.

Comment: As I wrote, Leaflet can work with any **valid** GeoJSON data. So your problem is how to get valid GeoJSON from your GeoJSON source.

Comment: I read https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-6 `A GeoJSON object has a member with the name "type".  The value of the member MUST be one of the GeoJSON types.` so that there can be only one type and thus your geometry with two types is not valid. But you can use a GeometryCollection https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193590/can-a-geojson-multigeometry-contain-a-multipoint-among-other-geometries.